# How to create Tkinter main menu

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pygame

I am currently creating a quiz game in Tkinter. This game consists of a login page, the quiz, a graph to show results and a pong game. The quiz and login use the Tkinter library for the GUI, the graph uses MatPlotLib and pong uses pygame. Is there any way that I would be able to link all of these modules in the main menu, for example creating a Tkinter GUI and then assigning a command to each button to launch the respective python files?

EDIT: Adding code that I have tried.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import sys
import time
import importlib


importlib.import_module('Quiz')

class Menu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        
        #Setting up the window
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("1350x800+50+50")
        self.master.title("Main Menu")

        self.quizLaunch = Button(self.master, text="Quiz", command = quizApplication)
        self.quizLaunch.pack()

root = Tk()
Menu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why not? do u have any code on which u have tried so far? If you put ur code inside of a function, and u can call the whole function with the button right?

Comment: Sure I have added some code that I have attempted!

Comment: can u actually just define a function and put all ur code inside of one module in it and then import that into the menu.py and then call it using button?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. You license content to Stack Overflow upon posting under CC BY-SA 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is completely possible. You can do this by importing packages like what you do in normal codes. You will be needed to import the following libraries to embed matplotlib into tkinter.

```
import matplotlib
import pygame
from tkinter import *
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

I recently made a basic GUI application using pygame in the python script along with tkinter library.

It would be great if you could post your code.

You can find the complete guide at:
https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I have posted the code that I have currently!

Comment: So this means basically you're just starting of with it. Then I will refer you to go through the link I provided. Will definitely give you an idea :)